# trying to find qt4 libraries on centos7

Tags: qt, qt4

I am installing the default QT on the base yum repos (version 4: `sudo yum qt qt-devel`. I can see that it includes the bin (in `/usr/lib64/qt4/bin`) and the includes (in `/usr/include/Qt` , `/usr/include/QtCore`). I am not sure where the lib files are, or if they are named in the same format as the qt3 lib directory (`/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib/libqt-mt.so.3`). Are these files in the same naming convention i.e. `libqt-mt.so.4`, or what would I be looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

Qt3 libraries are named libqt-?. Qt4, Qt5 libraries : libQt*, i.e.  uppercase Q.

- List files in an installed package: `$ rpm -ql [package name]`

List qt4 libraries, CentOS 7 :

```
$ rpm -ql qt | grep lib64
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtCore.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtDBus.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtNetwork.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtScript.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtScript.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtScript.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtSql.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtSql.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtSql.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtTest.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtTest.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtTest.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtXml.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtXml.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtXml.so.4.8.7
/usr/lib64/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4
/usr/lib64/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8
/usr/lib64/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8.7 
.
.
```